# SignalR 2.0 for iOS not working

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I am using a signalR library for iOS, called DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC: [here](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) is the git hub page.  I am trying to update this library to SignalR 2.0 within my project, since the backend has been updated to signalR 2.0.  I have finished updating AFNetworking to 2.0, since this is required for the new signalR 2.0 update.  After the update, I can only send messages through signalR, but cannot receive them.

This library worked fine before the update, though receiving messages through signalR was hit or miss; sometimes it would receive the appropriate messages, sometimes it would not receive anything.  I can see that after the update, the messages sent via iOS are received but the iOS app is not receiving any messages posted from the server (sending messages but not receiving).

My current guess to the problem is that there is something wrong with SocketRocket, which is one of the libraries the signalR library is built on top of.  The socketRocket library I am using is up-to-date, and I am going to test it with some break points to see if anything interesting happens.

One thing I noticed after the update is that the URL changed for sending requests.  The URL before was

> https://main/path/here/signalR?{params}

and now the path is

> https://main/path/here/signalR/signalR?{params}

I am not sure if this might be affecting the ability to establish connections correctly and I would not know how to check.

I do not totally understand the signalR library and how it's sending and receiving messages along web sockets.  If someone has experience with signalR in general or with the specific iOS library I am using, I would appreciate some help fixing this bug or even just a clear explanation of how signalR works.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The objective C library is not an officially supported library for SignalR so I'd recommend filing a bug on the GitHub repo.

Comment: The same problem. Can't receive anything from the server...